# WebSocket++, on_message event

Tags: c++, websocket++

I've got a problem with this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls_client.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/client.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/common/thread.hpp>

using namespace std;

class auth_client {
public:
    typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_client> client;
    typedef websocketpp::lib::lock_guard<websocketpp::lib::mutex> scoped_lock;
    typedef websocketpp::config::asio_client::message_type::ptr message_ptr;
    typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_client> client;

    auth_client() : m_open(false), m_done(false) {
        m_client.clear_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::all);
        m_client.set_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::connect);
        m_client.set_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::disconnect);
        m_client.set_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::app);

        m_client.init_asio();

        using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
        using websocketpp::lib::bind;

        m_client.set_open_handler(bind(&auth_client::on_open, this, ::_1));
        m_client.set_close_handler(bind(&auth_client::on_close, this, ::_1));
        m_client.set_fail_handler(bind(&auth_client::on_fail, this, ::_1));
        m_client.set_message_handler(bind(&auth_client::on_msg, this, ::_1));
    }

    void on_msg(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, message_ptr msg) {
        m_client.get_alog().write(websocketpp::log::alevel::app,
            "Connection opened, starting telemetry!");

        scoped_lock guard(m_lock);
        m_open = true;
    }

    void run(const std::string & uri) {
        websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;

        client::connection_ptr con = m_client.get_connection(uri, ec);
        if (ec) {
            m_client.get_alog().write(websocketpp::log::alevel::app,
                "Get Connection Error: " + ec.message());
            return;
        }

        m_hdl = con->get_handle();

        m_client.connect(con);

        websocketpp::lib::thread asio_thread(&client::run, &m_client);

        asio_thread.join();
    }

    void on_open(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
        scoped_lock guard(m_lock);
        m_open = true;
    }

    void on_close(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {
        scoped_lock guard(m_lock);
        m_done = true;
    }

    void on_fail(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl) {

        scoped_lock guard(m_lock);
        m_done = true;
    }

private:
    client m_client;
    websocketpp::connection_hdl m_hdl;
    websocketpp::lib::mutex m_lock;
    bool m_open;
    bool m_done;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auth_client c;

    std::string uri = "ws://localhost:9002";

    c.run(uri);
    return 0;
}
```

Just keep getting this error:
[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U5E7.png)

I'm just a beginner in CPP and don't understand all features.
First it said like it's can't understand "message_ptr"
But then I added:

```
typedef websocketpp::config::asio_client::message_type::ptr message_ptr;
```

And it still don't working.
How to fix it?

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please. All compiler errors verbatim in text format in your question.

Comment: I don't actually understand what do you want from me. I'm sorry, my native language is Russian. Actually, this is minimal-needed code to reproduce the problem, it's complete in one time..
I don't understand what argument I need to use for this event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add ::_2 to set_message_handler(), you only have ::_1. on_message() is bi-directional.

```
m_client.set_message_handler(bind(&auth_client::on_msg, this, ::_1, ::_2));
```

Comment: Ehh.. not I'm getting a lots of errors ><
Almost all in ws2def.h and winsock2.h, ws2ipdef.h, ws2tcpin.h, mswsock.h, winsock_init.h, socket_ops.h and everything is talking about "redefinition" of structs and "redefinition; different linkage"
What should I do?

Comment: I meant "now" I'm getting*

Comment: Not sure. I have an example you can copy which is built on os x, and compiles on FreeBSD as well. Did not compile on Linux (ubuntu). I haven't tried it on Windows. The repo is at https://github.com/kometen/cppkarusellrenn. It connects to a postgresql database and transmits data using json. You can see if if compiles and then remove json/postgresql if you don't need those. I use clang.

Comment: It's a server. I need a client.

Comment: OK. I have thought of making a client using websocketpp for a while so this could be an opportunity.

Comment: do you have a skype? It will be a lots of easier to communicate.

Comment: Yes. My nick is cguttesen. I'll be away a few hours but just look me up.